ibus-pinyin can't keep configuration

I'm using a translator, so the wording might be incorrect.
I'd be happy to provide it if more information is needed.

The configuration for ibus-pinyin falls back to the default settings after a reboot, logout, even a daemon restart.
I tried purging and reinstalling all ibus-related components, but it didn’t resolve the issue.
I suspect it might be related to the permissions of the configuration file or folder.
Ubuntu 24.10
cpt@ib:~$ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep ibus
gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64               install
ibus                        install
ibus-anthy                  install
ibus-data                   install
ibus-gtk:amd64                  install
ibus-gtk3:amd64                 install
ibus-gtk4:amd64                 install
ibus-libpinyin                  install
ibus-pinyin                 install
ibus-table                  install
libibus-1.0-5:amd64             install
libusb-1.0-0:amd64              install
libusbmuxd6:amd64               install
python3-ibus-1.0                install

